# Audio Missing - Blender 2.8 Video Editing

Tags: edit-mode, video

How can video be rendered with Blender 2.8 to include sound. Each of my attempts have failed:
- Render FFMpeg
- Render AVI Jpeg
- Sounds encoding checkbox cannot be checked because sound encoding subsection is missing from the Output and Render context panes in Blender 2.8 (in both Eevee and Cycles.
- Tried syncing time/speed of sound and clips
- Strip audio volume is engaged (0.9)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I open a new Blender scene in 2.8 and then go to the Output icon, set the File Format to FFmpeg, expand the new Encoding section and the scroll down to Audio. I can change the Audio Codec from No Audio to my required codec. With a completely new .blend file is that the same for you?

Comment: Thank you very much. I had looked over that context pane repeatedly, but I never realise that the encoding drop down was only available in FFmpeg. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: @rob Thank you for the answer. I also dont know about encoding drop down there. I think it should be answer than omments